# some explanations for mutex lock and unlock

Tags: c, multithreading, locking, mutex, synchronization

I'm working right now on synchronisation between process , specially on mutex and semaphore, so I found some videos and codes on that topic.

My questions are:

- When to put the `pthread_mutex_lock` before the `pthread_create` instead of putting it inside the thread function?
- The code below showing that I have put the lock before the `pthread_create`, and when I put it again in the thread function, I have exactly the same result, so what the difference between the two?

Is there any book that I can pick those things from it please just give its name.

The code:

```
  #include <stdio.h>
  #include <unistd.h>
  #include <pthread.h>

  int T[5];

  pthread_mutex_t mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;

  void* fct1(void* arg){
    int i = 0;

    while(i<5){
      //debut de la section critique

      T[i] = 2 * (i+1);
      printf("le thread 1 ecrit : %d\n",T[i]);

      i++;
    }
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
    //fin de la section critique
    pthread_exit(NULL);

  }

  void* fct2(void* arg){
    int i = 0;
    //debut de la section critique
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    while(i<5){

      printf("le thread 2 li : %d \n",T[i]);

      i++;
    }
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
    //fin de la section critique
    pthread_exit(NULL);
  }

  int main (){
    pthread_t T1 , T2 ;
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    pthread_create(&T1, NULL, fct1, NULL);
    pthread_create(&T2, NULL, fct2, NULL);

    pthread_join(T1, NULL);
    pthread_join(T2, NULL);

    return 0;
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A mutex shall *protect a concurrently used variable* from  ... well .. concurrent access.

To do this successfully the mutex needs to be locked just before the variable will be accessed. It can be unlock afterwards.

This in general is unrelated to any function calls (if not done via concurrently accessed function-pointers, which is not the case in the code you show).

Referring your example, the concurrently accesses variable is `int T[5]`.

So the code could look like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pthread.h>

int T[5];

pthread_mutex_t mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;

void* fct1(void* arg)
{
  int i = 0;

  while(i<5)
  {
    //debut de la section critique
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);

    T[i] = 2 * (i+1);
    printf("le thread 1 ecrit : %d\n",T[i]);

    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
    //fin de la section critique

    i++;
  }

  pthread_exit(NULL);

}

void* fct2(void* arg){
  int i = 0;

  while(i<5)
  {

    //debut de la section critique
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);

    printf("le thread 2 li : %d \n",T[i]);

    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
    //fin de la section critique

    i++;
  }

  pthread_exit(NULL);
}


int main ()
{
  pthread_t T1 , T2;

  pthread_create(&T1, NULL, fct1, NULL);
  pthread_create(&T2, NULL, fct2, NULL);

  pthread_join(T1, NULL);
  pthread_join(T2, NULL);

  return 0;
}
```